# Unable to create a new offer on stellar platform using nodejs

Tags: horizon, assets

As per stellar documentation they provide manageOffer function to create, update and delete an offer, i am enable to use this function can anybody please help me to give me some instructions or any code reference which help me to create new offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manage offer operation](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Operation.html#.manageOffer) is used to create a new offer. Just set the offer id to 0, or omit it.

> offerId   number | string  *optional*
>
> If 0, will create a new offer (default). Otherwise, edits an exisiting offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//initialize stellar sdk
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk')
        StellarSdk.Network.useTestNetwork();
        var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');
var op ={
                selling: selling_asset,
                buying: buying_asset,
                amount: amount,
                price: price,
                offerId:0 // for creating new offer id must be 0
              }
        var sourcePublicKey = sourceKeypair.publicKey();
        server.loadAccount(sourcePublicKey)
          .then(function(account) {
            var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
              // Add a manageOffer operation
              .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageOffer(op))
              .build();
//sign transaction
            transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);
            console.log(transaction.toEnvelope().toXDR('base64'));
            server.submitTransaction(transaction)
              .then(function(transactionResult) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(transactionResult, null, 2));
                console.log('\nSuccess! View the transaction at: ');
                console.log(transactionResult._links.transaction.href);
})
              .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('An error has occured:');
                console.log(err);                   
              });
          })
          .catch(function(e) {
            console.error(e);
          });
```

Comment: Would you mind improving your answer by adding explanations to your code.